# Correct way to update state inside reducer in redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

`

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const initialState = {

    getAllCountries: null,

    getAllStatesByCountry: null,

    getAllCitiesByState: null

}

export const locationSlice = createSlice({

    name: 'location',

    initialState: initialState,

    reducers: {

        getAllCountries: (state, action) => {

            state.getAllCountries = action.payload.data

        },

        getAllStatesByCountry: (state, action) => {

            state.getAllStatesByCountry = action.payload.data

        },

        getAllCitiesByState: (state, action) => {

            state.getAllCitiesByState = action.payload.data

        }

    }

});

export const {

    getAllCountries,

    getAllStatesByCountry,

    getAllCitiesByState

} = locationSlice.actions;
```

`
Is it the correct way to update state inside reducer. Because according to immer, we either mutate the state or return a new object, but in this code, only the reference is being changed.

I just wanted to know if this is the correct way?

Comment: yes, you are doing right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing the reference `state`, but you are modifying the object `state`. It's perfectly fine.

```js
// this modifies `state`. this is good
state.foo = bar

// this reassigns `state`/changes the reference. this is not supported!
state = bar

// this returns a new object. this is also good
return bar
```

For more information see [writing reducers with `immer`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers) in the Redux Toolkit documentation.